# Unknown column error with an index

Tags: mysql-5.5

I created a simple index associated with a timestamp column

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
    `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `ticker` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `comment` TEXT NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `link` VARCHAR(256) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `comment_hash` CHAR(32) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `feed` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `source` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `active` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `score` VARCHAR(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    `dttm` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ticker`, `comment_hash`),
    INDEX `time_index1` (`time`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

However when I try to do anything with the index, it gives me `SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'time_index1' in 'where clause'`

Sample queries:

```
select *
from data
where time_index1 = '2013-10-01 17:18:06'
```

or

```
select *
from data
order by time_index1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SELECT statement is referencing the name of the index instead of the indexed field.

Use this instead:

```
select *
from data
where time = '2013-10-01 17:18:06'
```

Comment: You're welcome!  Any chance you could upvote my answer, and perhaps mark it as correct?  See the up/down arrows to the left of my answer, and the check-mark below the down-arrow?  Click them!  Thanks!

Comment: Cant upvote, not enough points yet. Will accept it once cooldown is done!